# Jersey-Test-Framework - TestContainerException: The default test container factory, null, could not be instantiated

Tags: java, rest, maven, junit, jersey

I am writing test for RESTful web service using Jersey-Test-Framework. My REST service code is as follow -

```
package net.vsspl.mycontent.services;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.test.framework.AppDescriptor;
import com.sun.jersey.test.framework.JerseyTest;
import com.sun.jersey.test.framework.WebAppDescriptor;



public class LabelAPITest extends JerseyTest {

@Override
protected AppDescriptor configure() {
    return new WebAppDescriptor.Builder().build();
}

@Test
public void testGetAction() throws JSONException,
        URISyntaxException {
    WebResource webResource = client().resource("http://localhost:8080/Kalgudi").path("/rest/labels");
    JSONObject json = webResource.get(JSONObject.class);

    assertEquals("{\"labelId\":\"52529cb5e4b0c4219267eed2\",\"labelName\":\"Price Information\",\"labelDesc\":\"This is about a Price Information.\",\"parentLabelId\":\"0\",\"colourId\":\"524e5e5ae4b011a698175877\"}", 
                json.get("52529cb5e4b0c4219267eed2").toString());       
}
```

}

when I am running it as JUnit Test, getting following error -

```
com.sun.jersey.test.framework.spi.container.TestContainerException: The default test container factory, null, could not be instantiated
at com.sun.jersey.test.framework.JerseyTest.getDefaultTestContainerFactory(JerseyTest.java:408)
at com.sun.jersey.test.framework.JerseyTest.getTestContainerFactory(JerseyTest.java:273)
at com.sun.jersey.test.framework.JerseyTest.<init>(JerseyTest.java:165)
at net.vsspl.mycontent.services.LabelAPITest.<init>(LabelAPITest.java:21)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:195)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:244)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:241)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.jersey.test.framework.JerseyTest.getDefaultTestContainerFactory(JerseyTest.java:406)
... 25 more
```

I already tried with different dependencies in pom.xml like -

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

also

```
    <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
          <version>1.9</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-external</artifactId>
          <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

and

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-grizzly2</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

But none of them are working. Everytime getting same error. Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-external</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

With this 3 dependency your code will work fine remove the default junit dependency created by Maven..(Just keep this 3 dependency)