# The default test container factory, null, could not be instantiated

Tags: java, testing, junit, jersey

I think I have all necessary jars. I am getting error:

```
com.sun.jersey.test.framework.spi.container.TestContainerException: The default test container factory, null, could not be instantiated
    at com.sun.jersey.test.framework.JerseyTest.getDefaultTestContainerFactory(JerseyTest.java:408)
    at com.sun.jersey.test.framework.JerseyTest.getTestContainerFactory(JerseyTest.java:273)
    at com.sun.jersey.test.framework.JerseyTest.<init>(JerseyTest.java:165)
    at SimpleTest.<init>(SimpleTest.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:187)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.jersey.test.framework.JerseyTest.getDefaultTestContainerFactory(JerseyTest.java:406)
```

**code:**

```
import com.sun.jersey.test.framework.AppDescriptor;
import com.sun.jersey.test.framework.JerseyTest;
import com.sun.jersey.test.framework.WebAppDescriptor;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class SimpleTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    protected AppDescriptor configure() {
        return new WebAppDescriptor.Builder().build();
    }


    @Test
    public void test(){
        assertEquals(1,1);
    }

}
```

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25174768/1563512) might help. It could be missing dependencies.

Comment: @RCola You could have mentioned the exact solution which worked out for you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you might need to override Factory method getTestContainerFactory. Something like below :

```
 @Override
    protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() {
        return new GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory();
    }
```